# JSF 2.3.3 (Mojarra) <h:commandScript> Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: jsf, mojarra

I try to make use of the component

```
<h:commandScript />
```

with Mojarra 2.3.3 however IntelliJ highlights the tag with "Cannot resolve symbol'h:commandScript'".

These are my includes:

```
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Does it **run**??? Then it is an IDE issue

Comment: Thanks! I have to admit that I didn't try to run it - forgive ... that's stupid ... Maybe I should try something. But how comes that IntelliJ (latest version) doesn't recognize it?

Comment: Because IntelliJ unintelligently uses some hardcoded list instead of consulting the actual tld.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with '<f:websocket>'. Have reported it as a bug to JetBrains. Did one upgrade and that didn't fix it and the upgrade today hasn't either. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188937